# Azure Databricks RegEx: PatternSyntaxException

Tags: python, regex, azure, databricks, azure-databricks

I have a RegEx expression that has been running without fail for many months. As of today it no longer works. This command is running as part of a SQL magic cell in a Databricks notebook on Azure.

```
CAST
 WHEN NOT (phone REGEXP "^\\(?[2-9][0-8][0-9]\\)? ?[2-9][0-9]{2}-?[0-9]{4}\\b") THEN"S"
 ELSE "" 
END AS exception
```

The error I get is:

```
PatternSyntaxException: Unknown inline modifier near index 3
^(?[2-9][0-8][0-9])? ?[2-9][0-9]{2}-?[0-9]{4}
```

Does anyone know the cause of this issue or how to resolve it?

Many Thanks

Comment: This looks like your string literal requires 4 backslashes to introduce one backslash: `"^\\\\(?[2-9][0-8][0-9]\\\\)? ?[2-9][0-9]{2}-?[0-9]{4}\\\\b"`

Answer (score -1):

> PatternSyntaxException: Unknown inline modifier near index 3
> ^(?[2-9][0-8][0-9])? ?[2-9][0-9]{2}-?[0-9]{4}

- This exception is thrown from `Pattern`'s `compile()` and `matches()` methods.
- The constructor stores the specified `description`, `regex`, and `index` where the syntax error occurs in the `regex`. The `index` is set to `-1` when the syntax error location isn't known.
- check your  `String` is  syntactically valid regular expression:

```
boolean isRegex;
try {
  Pattern.compile(your regex string);
  isRegex = true;
} catch (PatternSyntaxException e) {
  isRegex = false;
}
```

**References:**
[Regular expressions in Java, Part 2: The Regex API](https://www.infoworld.com/article/3195301/java-101-regular-expressions-in-java-part-2.html?page=2)
[How to check if a string is a valid regex in Python?](https://python.tutorialink.com/how-to-check-if-a-string-is-a-valid-regex-in-python/)